# How do I `JOIN` these tables properly?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table being used to store aircraft inspection schedules for the current week, it is called `aircraft_sched`. There are two others that are relevant, one is called `aircraft_sched_options` which I need to `JOIN` to the first table, and the last table is called `aircraft`.

`aircraft_sched`:

```
column 1: AC_Reg (VARCHAR)(10),(PK),(FK -> `aircraft` PK)
column 2: Sched_Day1 (INT)(1),(FK -> `aircraft_sched_options` PK)
column 3: Sched_Day2 (INT)(1),(FK -> `aircraft_sched_options` PK)
column 4: Sched_Day3 (INT)(1),(FK -> `aircraft_sched_options` PK)
column 5: Sched_Day4 (INT)(1),(FK -> `aircraft_sched_options` PK)
column 6: Sched_Day5 (INT)(1),(FK -> `aircraft_sched_options` PK)
column 7: Sched_Day6 (INT)(1),(FK -> `aircraft_sched_options` PK)
column 8: Sched_Day7 (INT)(1),(FK -> `aircraft_sched_options` PK)
```

`aircraft_sched_options`:

```
column 1: SchedOpt_ID (INT)(1),(PK)
column 2: SchedOpt_Name (VARCHAR)(10)
column 3: SchedOpt_Color (VARCHAR)(7),
```

`aircraft`

```
column 1: AC_Reg (VARCHAR)(10),(PK)
column 2: AC_SN  (VARCHAR)(6)
column 3: AC_Year (VARCHAR)(4)
```

When a new aircraft is added to the system, I have it so it also adds it to the `aircraft_sched` table. I don't think this is the right way, but that's how it is right now. So the `aircraft_sched` table is always populated with the `AC_Reg` and the `Sched_DayX` cell is either a `0` for `NULL` or a `SchedOpt_ID` number corresponding to the schedule type selected.

The problem I'm facing is when I try to `JOIN` the `Sched_DayX` column to the `SchedOpt_ID` column. It sort of works when I only `JOIN` one column, but if I try to do more than one, then the row just disappears from my results.

Here is my code that "sort of" works:

```
<?php
$sql = ("
          SELECT 
             * 
          FROM 
             aircraft_sched 
          INNER JOIN aircraft_sched_options AS aso1 
             ON aircraft_sched.Sched_Day1 = aso1.SchedOpt_ID
");

if(!$result_sql = $mysqli->query($sql))
{
    echo QueryCheck("getting the aircraft schedule ","from the aircraft sched",$mysqli) . "Error No: " .$mysqli->errno;
}

while($ACSched = $result_sql->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class=\"ACSched_Reg\">" . $ACSched['AC_Reg'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"background:" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Color'] . ";\">" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"background:" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Color'] . ";\">" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"background:" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Color'] . ";\">" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"background:" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Color'] . ";\">" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"background:" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Color'] . ";\">" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"background:" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Color'] . ";\">" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"background:" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Color'] . ";\">" . $ACSched['SchedOpt_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

When I say it "sort of" works, I mean that it actually displays something as a result. The reason it doesn't work is because it shows the same result in each cell even if there is only one day with a schedule type assigned.

When I add the second `JOIN` to the query, like this:

```
$sql = ("
          SELECT 
            * 
          FROM 
            aircraft_sched 
          INNER JOIN aircraft_sched_options AS aso1 
            ON aircraft_sched.Sched_Day1 = aso1.SchedOpt_ID
          INNER JOIN aircraft_sched_options AS aso2 
            ON aircraft_sched.Sched_Day2 = aso2.SchedOpt_ID
 ");
```

...then it just doesn't return any rows which have a record.

I have been reading on `JOIN`s and how they work and the only way I can think of to fix the problem is to have a separate table for each `AC_Reg` so that each day of the week can be set to a `UNIQUE` column, but I don't believe that is the best way to accomplish the task.

**EDIT:**

Here are some screen shots to give a better visual.

`aircraft_sched`:

[image: aircraft_sched]

`aircraft_sched_options`:

[image: aircraft_sched_options]

My Code:

[image: php code]

Screen Display:

[image: what displays on the screen]

Comment: what's tbl_one for? i don't think that it's normalized, and joining non-normalized tables is a PITA

Comment: `tbl_one` is a scheduling table, where `reg` is the aircraft and the rest of the columns are the days of the week. `tbl_two` is for storing the name of the inspection being done, for example "B Check"

Comment: Please provide sample data for both tables and desired output based on that data. Post it in your question.

Comment: @AndrewFox whats the relationship b/w two table means how it relates any foreign key?

Comment: you should have 3 tables, table one for aircraft, table two for weekdays, table three for the checks.

Comment: @STTLCU Do I need the table for weekdays though? I mean, they never change, those columns are always going to be the same.

Comment: the "weekdays" table is just the collections of checks you made to the aircrafts. it's the relationship table, containing the plane id, the check id, and the weekday of the check.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. In that case you could consider tbl_one to be the "weekdays" table, I do have a separate one for the aircraft already. I didn't mention it because I didn't think it was relevant to the question. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly you need a join with table `tbl_two` **for each** column `Day`:

```
SELECT 
    aircraft_sched.AC_SN,
    IF(
       aso1.SchedOpt_Name IS NULL OR aso1.SchedOpt_ID = 0, 
       '-', 
       aso1.SchedOpt_Name
    ) as option1,
    IF(
       aso2.SchedOpt_Name IS NULL OR aso2.SchedOpt_ID = 0, 
       '-', 
       aso2.SchedOpt_Name
    ) as option2
FROM 
    aircraft_sched 
LEFT JOIN aircraft_sched_options AS aso1 
    ON aircraft_sched.Sched_Day1 = aso1.SchedOpt_ID
LEFT JOIN aircraft_sched_options AS aso2 
    ON aircraft_sched.Sched_Day2 = aso2.SchedOpt_ID

....
```

**EDIT:** I've updated the query and used `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to get the options because as you said some might be `NULL`

**UPDATE :** removed the join with `aircraft` and added check if option is null or id is 0 the `-` will be displayed

Comment: Ok, so I need to join them each separately instead of using the `AND` part that I had?

Comment: exactly, in order to get for each `Day` column from table `tbl_one` the  `Day_Name` and `Day_Color` from table `tbl_two`

Comment: I added this:

`INNER JOIN aircraft_sched_options AS acso1 ON acs.Sched_Day1 = acso1.SchedOpt_ID `

but now my table is blank. I know this doesn't really help you to help me, I will try to figure it out and get back.

Comment: I've updated my question to show more of my code including how I implemented your suggestion.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I'm not able to get it working. I did change your code slightly in that I removed the `INNER JOIN` because the `AC_Reg` column is already populated with the aircraft. I also have the default set to '0' in MySQL for the `Sched_DayX` columns.

Comment: I have taken some screen shots to show you exactly what everything looks like. My question is updated with them. Thanks :)

Comment: i removed the join with aircraft and add the check id option id is 0... also explain to me what was not working for you?

Comment: What I want to have happen is the cell to display the `aircraft_sched_option` name and color, but right now as you can see from the last screenshot, it's displaying the same option for the whole week when it should only appear on Monday.

Comment: ...as well for the first `AC_Reg` "MAD" it doesn't display anything.

Comment: its a bug in ur code : instead of displaying `$ACSched['SchedOpt_Name']` you should display `$ACSched['option1']`, `$ACSched['option2']` etc. pls try this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29104/discussion-between-andrew-fox-and-stephan)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the logic of your query, only rows with Day1 == Day2 == Day3 == ... == Day7 in tbl_one AND the value also equal to tbl_two.Day_ID should show up, can this help?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_one INNER JOIN tbl_two
    ON tbl_one.Day1 = tbl_two.Day_ID 
WHERE 
      tbl_one.Day1 = tbl_one.Day2
  AND tbl_one.Day1 = tbl_one.Day3
  AND tbl_one.Day1 = tbl_one.Day4
  AND tbl_one.Day1 = tbl_one.Day5
  AND tbl_one.Day1 = tbl_one.Day6
  AND tbl_one.Day1 = tbl_one.Day7
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't think I explained my question well enough the first time, I've updated it to give more detail.